# TWRP boot loop in Samsung Galaxy S3 mini (i8190L)

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, twrp, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

## Issue

TWRP start and still looping.

After tried to encrypt my device (`Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini` - `i8190L`) from Settings menu in Cyanogenmod rom. It started to encrypt but in some point it stop and said that encrypt end unexpected and data cannot be accesible anymore until I reset device (factory settings), after that TWRP did not start as is expected, it still restarting in a loop.

I do not know what else say, if you need more details, please ask me!

#### Tests

After this error, I have tried:

1. Reflashing the same Cyanogenmod rom.
2. Reflashing TWRP recovery img.
3. Flashing CWM recovery img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it by flashing PARAM image. It seems that encryption is not supported yet in our software version. Encrypting the device corrupts the PARAM partition.

I used Heimdall to do it and downloaded the PARAM file [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2432783).

I hope it helps you.