# S3 mini Teamwin boot loop

Tags: unbricking

I was running Novafusion's LineageOS 14.1 on my Samsung SIII mini but it was slow, so I decided to go back to Android 6.0.1.

I booted into recovery, formatted the cache partition to ext4, but left the data partition in f2fs, flashed Resurrection Remix 6.0.1.

When it booted I got an error "Encryption interrupted… you have to factory reset your phone" and I accepted. But I never enabled encryption on my phone.

Now it is stuck at teamwin logo screen flashing every 5 seconds or so. I can access download mode so:

I tried:

1. Flashing TWRP recovery using heimdall
2. Flashing LOS 14.1 using heimdall
3. Flashing Param.lfs using heimdall (reference https://android.stackexchange.com/a/130061/25234)

Now if I try to boot normally, it gets stuck on the Samsung Galaxy SIIImini logo. If I try booting to recovery I get the same boot loop as before.

Please help.

Comment: Now flash a full stock firmware and it should be fine

Comment: Some threads say you need to flash stock recovery too. Can't find that online.

Comment: The stock firmware already contains the recovery. Just use Heimdall to flash it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting an answer for the benefit of others that might end up in a similar situation.

### Download Stock firmware

This was the first hurdle. There are many sites and many versions. Finally I used the firmware from [sammobile.com](http://sammobile.com) for the gt-I8190 for Italy.

### Boot in Download mode

Next step was to boot in download mode by pressing Vol-, HOME and Power until it vibrates. Then release the buttons and connect the USB cable to the PC.

### Flash stock firmware

I'm using Linux so I installed heimdall, opened the heimdall GUI and flashed: Kernel (boot.img), Kernel2 (recovery.img), System and Cache. (Windows users would have to install Samsung drivers and ODIN from what I read but never actually used.)

### First boot

The first boot informed me of the same problem that the custom ROM had found about encryption of the Data partition and asked for a reset. This time the reset worked perfectly and on the second boot I was presented with the initial setup screen.